# The file "llllllllllllasas.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error. Laravel error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, imagen

Quiero subir muchas fotos a una tabla imagenes en la DB. Cuando recorro el array de fotos y intento guardarlas, solo me guarda la primera y en la segunda me tira el siguiente error.

```
The file "llllllllllllasas.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.
```

Controller

```
if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
        foreach ($request->file('img') as $image) {
              $img = new Imagen;
              $img->perro_id = $perro->id;
              $destinationPath = 'perrosimg/';
              $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
              $img->ruta = $filename;
              $img->save();
              $image->move( $destinationPath, $filename);
            }}
```

Como dije antes, la primera se mueve a la carpeta correspondiente y se guarda en la base de datos, pero la segunda me salta el error. El error esta en el metodo move() pero no entiendo porque. Gracias de antemano.

```
 dd($request->all());
    array:10 [▼
  "name" => "Alejo"
  "tamaño" => "asas"
  "edad" => "21"
  "raza" => "oiuuhihgih"
  "contacto" => "5´ñl´lñ"
  "comentarios" => "31324123"
  "button" => null
  "_token" => "TMa2POZWfH5Cl3hBs6ZeAS77WyM8Z2Jm5hx4xfXn"
  "imagenes_perro" => null
  "img" => array:3 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#1110 ▶}
    1 => UploadedFile {#1111 ▶}
    2 => UploadedFile {#1112 ▶}
  ]
]
```

Comment: es posible que el input 'img' tenga un solo archivo. ¿cómo haces la subida desde el lado cliente? ¿haces alguna validación del request en el servidor? podrías hacer un `dd($request->all()` y mostrarnos el resultado?

Comment: Si, ya lo edito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacerlo con `move()`, puedes usar el método `base_path()`, que devuelve la ruta completa a la raíz del proyecto, o si quieres devolver el directorio público, puedes usar `public_path()`.

```
$destinationPath = 'perrosimg';
$image->move(public_path($destinationPath), $filename);
```

Aunque usar `move` funciona y es muy usado, en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files) dice:

> El método de `move()` se puede usar para cambiar el nombre o mover un archivo existente a una nueva ubicación.

Y para la [subida de archivos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads), recomiendan usar `store()` o `put()`:

> Laravel hace que sea muy fácil almacenar archivos subidos utilizando el método de `store()` sobre una instancia de archivo subido. Llame al método de `store` con la ruta en la que desea almacenar el archivo subido.

Entonces, para tu caso puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
$filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
$destinationPath = 'perrosimg';
$image->storeAs($destinationPath, $filename, 'public');
```

pasándole como parámetros, primero la carpeta, segundo el nombre y tercero el disco.

Ojo, para tener en cuenta:

> El disco público está destinado a archivos que serán de acceso
>   público. De forma predeterminada, el disco público utiliza el
>   controlador local y almacena estos archivos en `storage/app/public`.
>   Para hacerlos accesibles desde la web, debe crear un enlace simbólico
>   de `public/storage` a `storage/app/public`.   Para crear el enlace
>   simbólico, puedes usar el comando de Artisan `storage:link` :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

> Una vez que se haya guardado un archivo y se haya creado el enlace
>   simbólico, puedes crear una URL para los archivos utilizando el
>   asistente de `asset`:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/file.jpg') }}"/>;
```

En fin, puedes usar `move()` si te sirve, después de todo, lo que hace es mover el archivo de una ubicación temporal que le da PHP. O también probar con `storeAs()`, va en ti.

En tu código:

```
if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
    foreach ($request->file('img') as $image) {
        $destinationPath = 'perrosimg';
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        $img = new Imagen;
        $img->perro_id = $perro->id;
        $img->ruta = $destinationPath.'/'.$filename;
        $img->save();

        $image->move(public_path($destinationPath), $filename);
    }
}
```

o

```
if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
    foreach ($request->file('img') as $image) {
        $destinationPath = 'perrosimg';
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        $img = new Imagen;
        $img->perro_id = $perro->id;
        $img->ruta = $image->storeAs($destinationPath, $filename, 'public');
        $img->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!