# Enviar 2 imagenes a la BD LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, imagen

quisiera enviar 2 imágenes a la bd al mismo tiempo, la cual una es el permiso de circulación y revisión técnica, por alguna razón solo eh podido enviar 1 imagen, si cambio algo del código en la bd guarda la ruta como un .tmp, alguien tiene una idea como puedo enviar 2 imagenes les adjunto el codigo de la subida de 1 sola imagen, por favor!.

```js
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        //hacemos referencia al modelo
        $entrada= $request ->all();
        //IMAGEN
        $p_circulacion = $request->file('img_r_tecnica');
        $r_tecnica = $request->file('img_p_circulacion');

        if ($archivo=$p_circulacion) 
        {
            //mantenemos el nombre original de la imagen
            $nombre=$archivo->getClientOriginalName();
            //creamos la carpeta o enviamos a la carpeta img
            //$archivo->move('images',$nombre);
            $destinationPath = 'images';
            $archivo->storeAs($destinationPath, $nombre, 'public');
             
            $entrada['img_p_circulacion']=$nombre;
        }

        Vehiculos::create($entrada);
        return  redirect()->route('vehiculos.index')->with('success','Registro eliminado satisfactoriamente');
    }
```

Comment: en el codigo que posteas, solo está manejando un solo campo de imagen. Creo que sería mejor que uses Storage en vez de Move para archivos subidos, mira esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/269991/92278), quizá te sirva.

Comment: si lo tengo entendido que pase 1 sola imagen, queria saber si alguien tiene alguna idea que sean 2?, como hacerlo, ya que lo he intentado todo y no puedo enviar 2, comenzare a cambiar al metodo storage como mencionas!

Comment: corrigo el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahí va una posible solución. Puse los comentarios directamente en el código.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    // pasas el objeto Request a un array
    $entrada = $request->all();
    // asignas los valores de los campos tipo file del request a variables
    $p_circulacion = $request->file('img_r_tecnica');
    $r_tecnica = $request->file('img_p_circulacion');

    if (!empty($p_circulacion)) // compruebas que la variable no esté vacía
    {
        //mantenemos el nombre original de la imagen
        $nombre = $p_circulacion->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = 'images';
        $p_circulacion->storeAs($destinationPath, $nombre, 'public');
        // sobreescribes el valor para el índice del array del request con el nombre del archivo
        $entrada['img_p_circulacion'] = $nombre;
    }
    if (!empty($r_tecnica)) // compruebas que la variable no esté vacía
    {
        //mantenemos el nombre original de la imagen
        $nombre = $r_tecnica->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = 'images';
        $r_tecnica->storeAs($destinationPath, $nombre, 'public');
        // sobreescribes el valor para el índice del array del request con el nombre del archivo
        $entrada['r_tecnica'] = $nombre; // cambia r_tecnica por el nombre del campo en BD
    }

    // insertas los datos en BD
    Vehiculos::create($entrada);
    // rediriges a la ruta 'vehiculos.index' con un mensaje
    return  redirect()->route('vehiculos.index')->with('success','Registro guardado satisfactoriamente');
}
```

Comment: me aparece este error "Impossible to create the root directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\fenix\public\images/C:/xampp/tmp"."

Comment: que código estás usando? en el codigo de la respuesta, storeAs va a guardar el archivo en 'tu-proyecto/storage/app/public/images', y no en donde te dice el error '\public\images'

Comment: a ver, revisare de nuevo

Comment: Gracias amigo! me sirvio, tenia unas variables mal, por eso me habia salido el error, pero ahora me lo sube super bien, gracias por tu tiempo!!!!!!